# Wrap every immediate group of objects, including text, except divs inside a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children

I'm trying to wrap every immediate group of objects that is not a div inside a wrap class. Is there any way

Input:

```
var $code = 
'Lorem Ipsum
 <p>Foo Bar</p>
 <div class="myclass"></div>
 <p>Foo Bar</p>
 <div class="myclass"></div>'

var $object = $('<div/>').html($code);
```

Wanted output:

```
 <div class="wrap">
    Lorem Ipsum
    <p>Foo Bar</p>
 </div>
 <div class="myclass"></div>
 <div class="wrap">
    <p>Foo Bar</p>
 </div>
 <div class="myclass"></div>
```

What I've tried:

```
 $object.contents().not('> .myclass').wrap('<div class="wrap"></div>');
```

Can someone help me please? I'm stuck here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't checked whether there is a more optimal way to do it, but there you go

```
var code =
    'Lorem Ipsum<p>Foo Bar</p><div class="myclass"></div><p>Foo Bar</p><div class="myclass"></div>'

var $object = $('<div/>').html(code);

var $obj = $();
$object.contents().each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('myclass')) {
        $obj.wrapAll('<div class="wrap"/>');
        $obj = $();
    } else {
        $obj = $obj.add(this)
    }
})
$obj.wrapAll('<div class="wrap"/>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X6Ff9/)